# Rinkeby etherscan verification pending but never happens

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I am trying to upload my `FundMe.sol` contract to `Etherscan.io` but when I run `brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network rinkeby` on the terminal it waits for `rinkeby etherscan` to process and verify the contract.
But the problem is it gets stuck in the verification process
[gets stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4y0p.png)
I kept it running and it has been 4 hours and it's still pending.
any solutions to this would be nice

Comment: Welcome! Please do NOT use an image to show code or errors. See "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the line of code that says wait() - if you have one, you have 1 in it and not another number. This is because the 1 means it waits for 1 block. If you don't have a wait() line in your code, add your deploy.py script to this post so I (or other people) can get a more detailed look of your issue.